# where more columns equal one value

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've got this repetitive query:

```
Model.where(:foo1 => "bar", :foo2 => "bar", :foo3 => "bar", ..., :foo9 => "bar")
```

I wondered if there was a nice way to shorten the code, similar to the opposite case:

```
Model.where(:foo => ["bar1, bar2, bar3, ..., bar9"])
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL. You can:

```
WHERE foo1 = foo2 = foo3 = ..... = foo9 = 'bar'
```

So you can try:

```
Model.where("foo1 = foo2 = foo3 = foo4 = foo5 = foo6 = foo7 = foo8 = foo9 = ?", "bar")
```

More or less: [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43cb2/43)

Comment: thanks, good one. Would it also be possible to do something similar with `OR` clauses?

iE: `.where("foo1 = 'bar' OR foo2 = 'bar' ... OR foo9 = 'bar'")`

Comment: When you're using `.where` that way, the first parameter is SQL. So yes, you can AND, OR, NOT, or anything else to your heart's content.

Comment: For OR clause, you can try the inversion of IN clause: `Model.where("'bar' IN (foo1, foo2, foo3, ..., foo8)")`

Answer (score 0):

Another option besides sql suggestion would be to use `inject` method:

```
query = [:foo1, :foo2, :foo3].inject({}){|hash, key| hash[key] = "bar"; hash}
# => {:foo1=>"bar", :foo2=>"bar", :foo3=>"bar"}
Model.where(query)
```